# UITextViewDelegate: how to set the delegate in code (not in IB...)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, uitextview

Suppose you have an UITextView and you would like to set the delegate of this UITextView.

First thing is that you put this in your header file:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> { ...
```

Then, if you were using IB, you would click the UITextView, and connect the delegate outlet with File's Owner. This would allow you to use commands such as `- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView {` etc.

Now, suppose you wanted to do this programatically. I found this suggestion on here:

```
textView.delegate = yourDelegateObject;
```

But I have no idea what 'yourDelegateObject' stands for. In IB, I am connecting with File's Owner... so in code, it would need to be textView.delegate = File's Owner. But what is the File's Owner in this case? myViewController? UIViewController?

I don't really understand the principle, I suppose. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated, set the `delegate` property of the `UITextView`. The most common delegate object is `self`.

To elaborate on "delegate object": the delegate object is the class (implementing the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol) that you want the events to respond to. For example, if you use a class instance instead of `self`, the `UITextView` will send its events to the implementations of the delegate methods in that class.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you want to assign a delegate to a current controller object, that is `self`:

```
textView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 2):

yourDelegateObject = self.

you can use

textView.delegate = self;

Answer (score 2):

The delegate is your UIViewController so it's

```
textView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put self as delegate:

```
textView.delegate = self;
```

So you need to put the function **- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView** in the implementation of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate can be any object, it doesn't have to be the class the textField is created in, though usually it is - whenever this is true you will set it to **self**, though you can set it to any instanced object that conforms to the protocol (whenever a formal protocol is defined for the object).

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it to self:

```
textView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
textView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure in your class you add UIItextFieldDelegate.

Example: say my class was called Pizza and my textField was called goodEats

```
class Pizza: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

//Then set the delegate in viewDidLoad 
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    goodEats.delegate = self

}
}
```